# Does camouflage paint affect your camo rating

Tags: world-of-tanks

Tanks can use 3 different paints, for the 3 types of maps: summer, winter and desert.

My question is does using these paints affect the range you can be spotted, or is it strictly cosmetics. If the latter is true, do certain paints affect it more? For example, would the pure white winter camo be more effective than the other winter paints when the map is very snowy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, these patterns give you a 5% bonus to your camouflage factor.

The camouflage you buy will only be used on maps which it is meant for. So winter camo will only function on winter maps and always give the full 5% bonus there. However if your tank only has the winter camo the bonus on a desert or summer map will be 0%

Comment: According to the [WoT wiki](http://wiki.wargaming.net/en/Battle_Mechanics#Camouflage), the effect of camouflage depends on the vehicle type. In the PC client v.0.9.19.1 I see the following: 4% for TD, 3% for LT/MT, 2% for HT/SPG.

Answer (score 2):

To add to the previous answer, it works both ways - it "hides" you by giving you boost to your camouflage rating, but it also "hides" you as you said - cosmetically. So while you have for example 2 different camo paints - and both gives you the same bonus to your camouflage rating, they look different so visually, you look different. Which in turn can hide you better.

Also bear in mind that the only "true" winter map is "Arctic Circle", others are (visually) a mix of spots of snow and grey terrain, so if you have pure white camo, you are more visible than someone who chooses white-grey camo.

But as the game uses markers for enemy/friendly tanks and if you point at the enemy, his "shape" shows as a red line, the camo (cosmetic part) isn't so necessary.

I usually chose pure white camo nevertheless, for "summer" type of maps (grass), you have big variety of camos, that's OK. But what I have problem with are "desert" camo paints of some nations - I am not satisfied with the big contrast of my camo paint and surrounding desert.

Last point - there are various mods for WoT, so even if you don't use a mod for graphical alteration of the game, your enemy/ies can and so for example enemy using hitbox skin mod will see you differently than you see yourself. So that cosmetic part is even less important.

What works all the time is that 5% bonus to your camo rating.

Comment: Not true when a tank is highlighted in red...